# Struts2 equivalent - actionError.get().hasNext()

Tags: java, struts2

What is the equivalent in Struts2 to the following line from action class:

```
if(actionError.get("myError").hasNext()){
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method in `ActionSupport` class [`getActionErrors()`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ValidationAware.html#getActionErrors()) that you can use along with the code

> ```java
> getActionErrors
>
> Collection<String> getActionErrors()
>
> Get the `Collection` of Action-level error messages for this action.
> ```
>
> Error messages should not be added directly here, as implementations
>   are free to return a new `Collection` or an [Unmodifiable Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection(java.util.Collection)).
>
> ```java
> Returns:
>     Collection of String error messages
> ```

and

```java
if (getActionErrors().contains("myError")) {
  //your code here
}
```